# Highlighted Content Webpart showing Duplicate Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, duplicate, hub-site, highlighted-content-web-part

My colleague has a hub site with a series of related SharePoint sites. On one site he has added a highlighted content web part to show policy documents stored in a document from one of the other sites. But it is showing duplicates of each file for some reason.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
PSB for ss of how we've set it up
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show how you configure the web part? Add screenshot of web part settings to your question.

Comment: Just added some images - Hope they help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if it's not a helpful answer, but there is no setting in the Highlighted content webpart to trim duplications. Also, KQL syntax does not support adding something like `trimduplicates=true` to the query.

You can try experimenting with the filters instead of KQL to see if you can get rid of duplicates this way.